# Luigi dependencies specification issue with a separate task

Tags: luigi

I have `3` `Luigi` tasks: first generates an output file that is written to `hadoop`, second - uses this output file to load it into `Elasticsearch`, third one - gets a completely separate file and also loads it into `Elasticsearch`. Third task is rather disconnected from the first two, but I want it to be run when the first two are finished. There can be multiple files (of the same type) fed into the first task, so in the second one I specify the dependencies like that:

```
def requires(self):
    return [SeqrVCFToMTTask()]
```

`SeqrVCFToMTTask` being the first task. It works fine, so first two tasks run perfectly. Now, when I try to specify dependency in the same way in the third task:

```
def requires(self):
    return [SeqrMTToESTask()]

(`SeqrMTToESTask` - name of the second task).
```

It fails with the error:

> raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
>   elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, '')

and the final `luigi` task output looks like that:

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 3 tasks of which:
* 1 complete ones were encountered:
    - 1 SeqrVCFToMTTask(...)
* 1 failed:
    - 1 SeqrMTToESTask(...)
* 1 were left pending, among these:
    * 1 had failed dependencies:
        - 1 SeqrGenesQCToESTask(...)

This progress looks :( because there were failed tasks

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

I know it has nothing to do with `Elasticsearch` because the `3rd` task - `SeqrGenesQCToESTask` - runs fine separately when the dependencies are omitted (just uncommenting `requires`). How should I specify dependencies here correctly? The only thing that I need is for the `3rd` task to start running after the first two are finished.

> Update

More detailed code:

```
class SeqrVCFToMTTask(HailMatrixTableTask):
    reference_ht_path = luigi.Parameter(...
    ...
    ...

    def run(self):
        self.read_vcf_write_mt()

    def read_vcf_write_mt(self, schema_cls=SeqrVariantsAndGenotypesSchema):
    ...
    ...

class SeqrMTToESTask(HailElasticSearchTask):
    dest_file = luigi.Parameter()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # TODO: instead of hardcoded index, generate from project_guid, etc.
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def requires(self):
        return [SeqrVCFToMTTask()]

    def output(self):
        filename = self.dest_file
        return getTarget(filename)

    def run(self):
        mt = self.import_mt()
        row_table = SeqrVariantsAndGenotypesSchema.elasticsearch_row(mt)
        self.export_table_to_elasticsearch(row_table, self._mt_num_shards(mt))

class SeqrGenesQCToESTask(luigi.Task):
    source_path = luigi.Parameter(...
    ...
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._es = ElasticsearchClient(host=self.es_host, port=self.es_port)

    def requires(self):
        return [SeqrMTToESTask()]

    def output(self):
        # TODO: Use https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.contrib.esindex.html.
        filename = self.dest_file
        return getTarget(filename)

    def run(self):
        // Doing some data transformations, then 
        // Exporting data to Elasticsearch


class HailMatrixTableTask(luigi.Task):
     source_paths = luigi.Parameter(...
     ...
     ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            # Locally it should be '_FrozenOrderedDict' but on AWS for an unknown reason only 'FrozenOrderedDict' works
            self.source_paths = list(json.loads(self.source_paths, object_pairs_hook=luigi.parameter._FrozenOrderedDict))
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            self.source_paths = [self.source_paths]

    def requires(self):
        # We only exclude globs in source path here so luigi does not check if the file exists
        return [VcfFile(filename=s) for s in self.source_paths if '*' not in s]

    def output(self):
        filename = self.dest_path
        return getTarget(filename)

    def complete(self):
        # Complete is called by Luigi to check if the task is done and will skip if it is.
        # By default it checks to see that the output exists, but we want to check for the
        # _SUCCESS file to make sure it was not terminated halfway.
        filename = self.dest_path
        full_path = os.path.join(filename, '_SUCCESS')
        return getTarget(full_path).exists()

    def run(self):
        // Import file, then output in different format

class HailElasticSearchTask(luigi.Task):
    project_guid = luigi.Parameter(...
    ...
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.es_index:
            self.es_index = compute_index_name(args=public_class_props(self))
        self._es = ElasticsearchClient(host=self.es_host, port=self.es_port)

    def requires(self):
        return [VcfFile(filename=self.source_path)]

    def run(self):
        mt = self.import_mt()
        # TODO: Load into ES

    def import_mt(self):
        return hl.read_matrix_table(self.input()[0].path)

    def export_table_to_elasticsearch(self, table, num_shards):
        // Exports to ES index
```

> Update

I suspect it happens because the `3rd` task - `SeqrGenesQCToESTask` - opens up connection to `Elasticsearch` and then the `2nd` task - `SeqrMTToESTask` - can't output to `Elasticsearch` due to that since the error happens there, in `SeqrMTToESTask` on the line:

```
self.export_table_to_elasticsearch(row_table, self._mt_num_shards(mt))
```

Comment: Is there any way you can show us more specifically what your tasks look like?

Comment: They are really simple, that's why I thought it is not really needed. But I will update the question in a minute

Comment: Please, see updated question

Comment: In the requires for `SeqrGenesQCToESTask`, are you setting the `dest_file` parameter for `SeqrMTToESTask`? Seems important to me.

Comment: I omitted this part, but its defined like that: `dest_file = luigi.Parameter()`. I am not sure what you mean, how can I define in one class a parameter of another and for what? All of the parameters (defined at the top of each class) are supplied from the config file that I additionally feed while running the `luigi` pipeline.

Comment: `dest_file` for `SeqrMTToESTask` in the config is defined just as an empty file `_SUCCESS_TO_ES` since it does not really need to output anything to disc, but write the data to `Elasticsearch`. I would expect then that this `_SUCCESS_TO_ES` is read in somehow by the `SeqrGenesQCToESTask` `luigi` task and then starts executing.

Comment: It'd be really great if you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Its' not possible, sorry. I suspect that since its `Elasticsearch` error, it may be that both tasks somehow try connecting to it since both tasks need to write into it and that somehow fails the pipeline and not just some dependencies issue.

Comment: I updated the question with what I believe is the root cause for the error. I don't yet know though how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to ultimately solve it and there were multiple issues with the `luigi` pipeline set up and not with `Elasticsearch`:

1. The reported error was occurring because I was calling `3rd` task - `SeqrGenesQCToESTask` - with the parameter that the second task was supposed to also get:

   > LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH=luigi_pipeline/configs/seqr-loading-local-GRCh38.cfg python -u gcloud_dataproc/submit.py --cpu-limit 4 --num-executors 2 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory=4g --hail-version 0.2 --run-locally luigi_pipeline/seqr_loading.py SeqrGenesQCToESTask --local-scheduler --spark-home $SPARK_HOME --project-guid sample

Previously I was just having `SeqrMTToESTask` instead of `SeqrGenesQCToESTask` but the command stayed the same, so by just changing the task, I omitted `project-guid` parameter since it was not specified in `luigi_pipeline/configs/seqr-loading-local-GRCh38.cfg`

2. After fixing the missing parameter issue, the pipeline was still failing because I needed to explicitly output an empty file at the end of the `run` method of `SeqrMTToESTask`, but I thought that `luigi` is doing that automatically:

   ```
   with self.output().open('w') as out_file:
       out_file.write('{} task complete!'.format(type(self).__name__))
   ```

`self.output()` returns `hdfs.target`:

https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/luigi/contrib/hdfs/target.html

After fixing these two the pipeline was successfully run, and so the specification of the dependency was actually done right at the very beginning in `SeqrGenesQCToESTask`:

```
def requires(self):
    return [SeqrMTToESTask()]
```